# FIWARE Orion: return subscription id

Tags: fiware-orion

When creating a subscription, it would be nice to return the subscription ID.

For instance, the following code doesn't return anything :

```
curl localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d @- <<EOF
{
  "description": "A subscription to get info about Room1",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "Room1",
        "type": "Room"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "pressure"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://localhost:1028/accumulate"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "temperature"
    ]
  },
  "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 5
}
EOF
```

In the subscription case, the resource id is generated server-side (with difference to the entities endpoint, where the id is decided client-side).

It would be nice to return it in the POST call, is there any way to do this?

Comment: What are the HTTP Headers of the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscription ID is retrieved in `Location` header in the response to the subscription creation request, eg:

```
Location: /v2/subscriptions/5b991dfa12f473cee6651a1a
```

More details in the [NGSIv2 API specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) (check "Create Subscription" section).

Comment: Thanks, that's great as always. Any reason why the id or full subscription is not returned in the response body? It's practical for some applications.

Comment: The reason is that the usage of Location header in responses to provide the resource id in creation operations is a common pattern in RESTful APIs.